# How to measure instantaneous CPU power dissipation?

Tags: cpu, power, cooling, measurement, undervolting

I would like to accurately measure the (instantaneous) electrical power that my laptop's CPU is dissipating. I don't want to measure the power draw of the entire machine using electrical measurement equipment in the mains line, but only of the CPU. I'm running Windows.

I know that a solution for this exists from the Linux command line, but I don't run Linux anymore. But maybe a related question here: how accurate is the value given by the Linux command line utility?

The time resolution isn't critical, but faster sampling is better than slower of course.

The background to my question: I have been sensitized to fan noise by a poorly written BIOS-level fan control many years ago (thanks Sony), and am since then concerned with it and would like to get rid of it as best as possible. Therefore I would like to investigate quantitatively how undervolting the CPU will affect the power dissipation.

I have some vague idea of the expected scaling with clock rate and gate voltage, but it would be very nice to actually measure it. Also to compare it to the specified thermal design power (TDP) of the manufacturer.

First post here after a while (last time I was lynched), so please be gentle. I thank you in advance for considering my question.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://superuser.com/help/closed-questions). If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: If you are referring to `powertop`, then that is only an  estimate.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have edited my question after having read the advice around "What does it mean if a question is "closed"?". Can I ask back why this community is so toxic and is it only towards newcomers?

Comment: @Bib Yes, I was referring to powertop, but was afraid to mention it out of fear that my question would be instantly closed like last time I asked a similar question. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: Maybe I can ask a meta question here: The first time I asked a similar question to the one above on here it was closed within minutes. I then looked at the automatic message on why questions get closed and edited the question in order to make it comply with the platform rules. But since it was closed, I couldn't expect answers any more on the original question. So I had to ask the question again (now complying with the rules better). But since I did that the question has been marked as duplicate? I mean how is a person supposed to do this, even, correctly?

Comment: @george When you edit your closed question it will go into the reopen queue where the community will vote on whether it is suitable to be reopened.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you for this information! Is there statistics on what fraction of edits get reopened?